# checkbox of particular row in custom listview

Tags: android, checkbox

am having a custom listview in that checkbox and textview is present..

if i click on row 1 check box then only that row chewk box is checked.
if i click on second row then second row checkbox is selected and first
row is unselected.if i click on third row then third row check box is
selected and second row is unselected ...

so particular row click item checkbox only has tobe selected...

but here am getting all the checkbox are selecting ...how to solve this..

package com.example.testdata;

```
public class Newcard extends Activity {
 MyAdapter adapter; 
CheckBox check=null;
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater lay;
MyApplication app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.newcard);
app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cardlist);

adapter =new MyAdapter(this, app.arryList);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context = null;
 ArrayList<String> items= null;

public MyAdapter(Newcard newcard, ArrayList<String> items,
    ArrayList<String> items1) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub     
this.items = items;         
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return items; 

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

View layout = null;
TextView produ = null;  

TextView desc = null;
Button edit = null;



if (convertView == null) {

    lay = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    layout = lay.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
} else {
    layout = convertView;
}

produ = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.card);
produ.setText("" +app.arryList.get(position));

check = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  System.out.println("data "+app.arryList.get(position)); 

    }
});

return layout;

}

}

}

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:text=""
     
       />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/card"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1"
      android:text=""
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:textSize="15dip"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above is not complete, I can't see where you create the form/checkboxes. But, I see this line: `check = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);`
You are probably using radiobuttons and casting them to a checkbox? Radiobuttons are used to select just one of the multiple options, like your behaviour. You need to be sure you created checkboxes and not radio buttons to solve the problem.